# Want FB login functionality with customize button working both when FB App is installed and when not?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sick of finding and searching this thing. I want a FB login function working on a Button click. I dont want FB login Button for this, plus which FB SDK to use for it,latest one i.e 4.8 doesn't seems to use Session for login. I have tried FB Login Manager also,but sonetimes not gives authentication when native FB app is installed and if then not providing me email.(I have tested it). Please Please provide me a way which FB SDK I use to make my work done. I have use Session but it gives graph Object null when FB app is installed. thanks and please guide me on this.

Comment: I know there were many post for this but I want a robust way to do login and get basic user info both when FB app is installed and not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code accordingly in the `CustomCallback` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button facebook;
    private LoginManager loginManager;
    private CustomFacebookCallback callback;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Facebook initialize
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.GRAPH_API_DEBUG_INFO);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.DEVELOPER_ERRORS);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_RAW_RESPONSES);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init button
        facebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook);

        // Instantiate parts and variables
        callback = new CustomFacebookCallback();

        // Callback Manager initialize
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        //===================
        // Facebook Login
        //===================

        // 1) Permissions
        final ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("public_profile");
        permissions.add("user_friends");

        // 2) Set login function to button
        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions);
                loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
            }
        });
    }

    private class CustomFacebookCallback implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.d("Result : " , object.toString());

                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("Facebook", "Canceled!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e("Facebook", "Error!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is giving me above output. I am using FB SDK 4.8 for this which is basically a aar file which I have added ot could you please tell me which SDK will be better for this thing.

Comment: Actually it is not working in my case with 4.8.1 SDK